# Washed out and faded images when generating a PDF within a .net core project

Tags: .net-core, wkhtmltopdf, pdf-conversion

I have a .net core project where I am saving an HTML template string into a PDF via [DinkToPdf](https://github.com/rdvojmoc/DinkToPdf).  Whilst I am successfully generating a PDF file, I am seeing some odd behaviour around images where they are appearing washed out/faded.

Please note I do not have this issue with the generated HTML itself.

The two links below show how the images should (and do within the HTML template) appear and how they appear within the PDF.

- [How the images appear within the HTML template.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IRuLt.jpg)
- [Images appear faded from the generated PDF file.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v9CPB.jpg)

Interestingly, the first image in the generated PDF does not suffer from this issue (not shown).  I have compared this image with the other "washed out" images and the key difference was around their DPI (72dpi vs. 96dpi), as a test I updated one of the faded images to the same DPI but the problem persists.

Below is my PDF generation code:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Generates the specified HTML content into a PDF byte array.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="htmlContent">Content of the HTML.</param>
    /// <param name="documentTitle">The document title.</param>
    /// <returns>Byte array of the generated PDF contents.</returns>
    public static byte[] Generate(string htmlContent, string documentTitle)
    {
        var converter = new BasicConverter(new PdfTools());

        var document = new HtmlToPdfDocument
        {
            GlobalSettings
                =
                    {
                        ColorMode = ColorMode.Color,
                        Orientation = Orientation.Portrait,
                        PaperSize = PaperKind.A3,
                        DocumentTitle = documentTitle
                    },
            Objects =
                {
                    new ObjectSettings
                        {
                            PagesCount = true,
                            HtmlContent = htmlContent,
                            WebSettings =
                                {
                                    DefaultEncoding = "utf-8"
                                }
                        }
                }
        };

        // Return the PDF content in a byte array.
        return converter.Convert(document);
    }
```

And the HTML code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <!-- Tagging -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <!-- Titles -->
  <title>Page Title</title>
  <!-- Styles -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-/Y6pD6FV/Vv2HJnA6t+vslU6fwYXjCFtcEpHbNJ0lyAFsXTsjBbfaDjzALeQsN6M" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <style>
    body {
      margin-left: 10px;
      margin-top: 30px;
    }
    
    #content {
      width: 100%;
      margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
    }
    
    h1 {
      float: right;
      text-transform: uppercase;
      white-space: nowrap;
    }
    
    h2 {
      color: #1E86B1;
      font-size: x-large;
    }
    
    h2.ellipsis {
      overflow: hidden;
      text-overflow: ellipsis;
      width: 500px;
    }
    
    a {
      color: #1E86B1;
      font-weight: bold;
    }
    
    a:hover {
      color: #1E86B1;
    }
    
    .thead-inverse th {
      background-color: #1E86B1;
    }
    
    td {
      text-align: right;
    }
    
    .container {
      clear: both;
    }
    
    .logo {
      width: 100px;
    }
    
    .screenshot {
      border: solid 1px #ccc;
      float: right;
    }
    
    .intro {
      margin-bottom: 0;
      margin-top: 30px;
    }
    
    .intro a {
      color: #fff;
      font-weight: bold;
    }
    
    .intro h2 {
      font-size: x-large;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0 0 15px 0;
    }
    
    .composition-cards p:last-of-type {
      margin-bottom: 30px;
    }
    
    .cards {
      text-align: center;
      width: 100%;
    }
    
    .card {
      display: inline-block;
      float: left;
      margin: 0 0 6px 6px;
      text-align: left;
      width: 49%;
    }
    
    .card-body h2 {
      border-bottom: solid 1px #000;
      color: #000;
      font-size: 4rem;
      font-weight: 700;
      margin: 0;
      margin-bottom: 6px;
      padding-bottom: 6px;
    }
    
    .card:nth-child(3n) {
      margin-right: 0;
    }
    
    .card-img-top {
      border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .125);
    }
    
    .clip {
      background-clip: content-box;
      display: table;
      margin-left: 0;
      overflow: hidden;
      padding-right: 0;
      padding-top: 95px;
      position: relative;
    }
    
    .clip>div>p {
      color: #fff;
      font-size: large;
      margin: 0;
      width: 95%;
    }
    
    .clip>div {
      display: table-cell;
      vertical-align: middle;
    }
    
    .clip>div:first-child {
      background-color: #42BCE2;
      border: solid 1px #42E0E2;
      border-right: none;
      border-bottom-left-radius: 15px;
      border-top-left-radius: 15px;
      padding: 30px 0 30px 30px;
    }
    
    .clip-screenshot {
      border: solid 1px #eee;
      padding: 0;
    }
    
    .compositions h3 {
      color: #fff;
      font-size: large;
      text-transform: uppercase;
    }
    
    .compositions .row .col {
      background-color: #42BCE2;
      border: solid 1px #42E0E2;
      border-radius: 15px;
      margin: 5px;
      padding: 20px;
    }
    
    .divider,
    .no-divider {
      border-bottom: solid 1px #eee;
      padding: 30px 0 30px 0;
    }
    
    .divider:last-of-type,
    .no-divider {
      border-bottom: none;
      margin-bottom: 10px;
    }
    
    .divider:last-of-type>div>div {
      color: #666;
      text-align: center;
    }
    
    .divider:last-of-type>div>div a {
      font-weight: normal;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="content">
    <div class="container no-divider">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col composition-cards">
          <div class="cards">
            <div class="card">
              <img class="card-img-top" src="{serverProcessingImage}">
              <div class="card-body">
                <h4 class="card-title">Card Title</h4>
                <p class="card-text">
                  Content here...
                </p>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="card">
              <img class="card-img-top" src="{htmlFilesImage}">
              <div class="card-body">
                <h4 class="card-title">Card Title</h4>
                <p class="card-text">
                  Content here...
                </p>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="card">
              <img class="card-img-top" src="{imagesImage}">
              <div class="card-body">
                <h4 class="card-title">Card Title</h4>
                <p class="card-text">
                  Content here...
                </p>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="card">
              <img class="card-img-top" src="{javaScriptImage}">
              <div class="card-body">
                <h4 class="card-title">Card Title</h4>
                <p class="card-text">
                  Content here...
                </p>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="card">
              <img class="card-img-top" src="{otherResourcesImage}">
              <div class="card-body">
                <h4 class="card-title">Card Title</h4>
                <p class="card-text">
                  Content here...
                </p>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="card">
              <img class="card-img-top" src="{styleSheetsImage}">
              <div class="card-body">
                <h4 class="card-title">Card Title</h4>
                <p class="card-text">
                  Content here...
                </p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

The images themselves are pulled in and converted into byte arrays - these are then Base64 encoded into the HTML template.  The same code to pull down and encode the images is used so I do not currently see this as the root cause.

Please do share any thoughts/suggestions with me.  Thanks, Ben.

Answer (score 2):

After stripping back the template code to various stages, I spotted my class *card-img-top* had a bottom border colour value set via RGBA.

As a quick test, I removed this class and the issue was resolved.  I then altered the RGBA value with a hex code instead and the issue is no longer replicable.

Doing some further research this looks to have been a known issue within WKHTMLTOPDF: https://github.com/wkhtmltopdf/wkhtmltopdf/issues/1932